# Is it possible to combine two conditions

Tags: c#

I have these two conditions:

```
            if (someOtherStuff && Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
            }

            if (someOtherStuff && Keyboard.Modifiers == (ModifierKeys.Control | ModifierKeys.Shift))
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
```

I was wondering if it is possible to combine these two `if clauses` to one? or the way I have it is correct? If they hold the `Control` button and also if they hold the `Control and Shift` button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `ModifierKeys` enum is marked with the `Flags` attribute, you can use [bitwise AND](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND) to check to see if the key combinations **include** the `Control` key, which I believe is what you are after:

```
if (someOtherStuff && ((int)Keyboard.Modifiers & (int)ModifierKeys.Control) != 0)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Comment: That would return true for `Ctrl + Alt` which would return false in the code.

Comment: @DStanley I assumed he might have wanted Ctrl+ anything to satisfy the condition...

Comment: what is keys in (int)keys ? Thanks

Comment: @Blake That was supposed to be `Keyboard.Modifiers`. My bad.

Answer (score 2):

```
if ((someOtherStuff && Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control) ||
 (someOtherStuff && Keyboard.Modifiers == (ModifierKeys.Control | ModifierKeys.Shift))
{
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
if (someOtherStuff && (Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control ||
                       Keyboard.Modifiers == (ModifierKeys.Control | ModifierKeys.Shift)))
{
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```

or was there something else you had in mind?